# How to make text to fix a div

Tags: html, css

I am creating a table of contents using divs and a grid layout. However when i use grid-template-column i expect to see the my divs to arrange in columns, but my text is overflowing.
How can i make my text fit inside the box and what am i doing wrong?

```html
<style>
body{

background-color:grey;

}
.grid-item {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.grid-item {
  padding: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  **display: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  /* This is what i did to fit my content in my div but it did not work*/left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% -50%)**
}
.grid {
  padding: 2% 4% 0px;
}
span {
  line-height: 0.1px;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 100px;
}
</style>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <h1><span style="float:left;">Grid</span></h1>
    <h1><span style="float:right;">1</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <h1><span style="float:left;">Grid</span></h1>
    <h1><span style="float:right;">2</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <h1><span style="float:left;">Grid</span><span style="float:right;">3</span ></h1></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><h1><span style="float:left;">Grid</span><span style="float:right;">4</span></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The layout i want to create**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGo97.png

Comment: `display: absolute;` - `absolute` is an invalid value for the `display` property; if you want to use CSS grid then use `display: grid`, if you want to absolutely position elements, use: `position: absolute;` (hint: you almost always don't want to use absolute positioning). Can you share an image that shows the layout you actually do want to create?

Comment: Title. Fix or fit?

Comment: Please what do you mean

Comment: why did you specifically use `100px` and `200px` value in here `grid-template-columns: 200px 100px;`?

Comment: Because that what the guy did in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zBsdzdE4sM&t=125s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David mentioned earlier, `display: absolute` is an invalid value for the `display` property. To solve your issue you have several options:

- Change grid column width
- Change font size
- Change padding

**1. Changing grid column width:**

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 150px;
}
```

**2. Changing font size.** Try to replace `<h1>` elements with smaller title tags or manipulate the CSS code to adjust `<h1>` font size.

**3. Changing padding:**

```
.grid-item {
  padding: 20px;
}
```